# FBSqlException no método INSERT com Returning

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um INSERT no meu banco(FireBird) com Returning para retornar o ID cadastrado, porém, quando o chega na linha de `stmt.executeUpdate()` eu recebo a exception FBSqlException.

Método Insert:

Obs.1: Estou utilizando netbeans.

```
public int insereBanco(BancoCTR bancoCTR) {
        try {
            conn = Conexao.obtemConexao();
            String insert = "INSERT INTO BANCO VALUES (null, ?) RETURNING "
                    + "BCO_CODIGO";

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            stmt.setString(1, bancoCTR.getBcoNome());
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();


            if (i < 1){
                return -1;
            }else{
                rSet = stmt.executeQuery();
            }


            if (rSet.next()) {
                return rSet.getInt(1);
            } else {
                return -2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao inserir banco: " + e.getMessage());
            return -3;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Como o returning que estava causando o problema, resolvi com uma gambiarra.

vou deixar aqui, para caso alguém também não encontre uma forma adequada de resolver:

```
public int insereBanco(BancoCTR bancoCTR) {
        try {
            conn = Conexao.obtemConexao();
            String insert = "INSERT INTO BANCO VALUES (null, ?)";

            stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
            stmt.setString(1, bancoCTR.getBcoNome());
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();


            if (i < 1){
                return -1;
            }else{
                //Gambiarra ====================================================
                stmt = null;
                String codigo = "SELECT MAX(BCO_CODIGO) FROM BANCO";

                stmt = conn.prepareStatement(codigo);                
                rSet = stmt.executeQuery();
                //==============================================================
            }           

            if (rSet.next()) {
                return rSet.getInt(1);
            } else {
                return -2;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Erro ao inserir banco: " + e.getMessage());
            return -3;
        }finally{
            try{
            conn.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Erro ao fechar conexão: " + e.getMessage());
                return -4;
            }
        }
    }
```